# Flash IDE Stage3d and Hardware Acceleration setting

Tags: flash, gpu, stage3d

When using the Flash IDE for publishing Stage3D (GPU enabled) projects there is an option in Flash for Hardware Acceleration.

My question is, what effect, if any does changing this have on the ability of your application to make use of the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

Stage3D can only be run on the video hardware if the HTML embed contains wmode=direct. If you're using Stage3D you **must** use the 'Level 1 - Direct' option.

Here's a description of those options:

Level 1 – Direct: Direct mode improves playback performance by allowing Flash Player to draw directly on the screen instead of letting the browser do the drawing.

Level 2 – GPU: In GPU mode, Flash Player utilizes the available computing power of the graphics card to perform video playback and compositing of layered graphics. This provides another level of performance benefit depending on the user's graphics hardware. Use this option when you expect that your target audience will have high-end graphics cards when viewing your SWF file.

[Flash Professional Help / Publish settings](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/publish-settings-cs5-5.html)

[Flash glossary: Hardware acceleration](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_hardware_accel.html)

[The wmode parameter demystified](http://labs.almerblank.com/2011/03/the-wmode-embed-parameter-de-mystified/)

[Flash 11 Stage3D tutorial](http://www.mcfunkypants.com/2011/flash11-stage3d-tutorial-handling-init-errors/)

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add this blog post since it has some very useful and clearly explained information.
http://www.kaourantin.net/2008/05/what-does-gpu-acceleration-mean.html